# how to find an amount of certain duplicates in mysql table?

Tags: mysql, database

So I have a table with persons.
This table connects with vehicles with manyToMany.
I need to find how many times does id appear on the table person_vehicle.
How can I do this?
Thanks everybody for asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two suggestion.

**For all the names:**
Gives number of times the names are repeated.

```
SELECT count(name) FROM persons GROUP BY name;
```

**Specifically for the jake:**

```
SELECT count(name) FROM persons WHERE name = "Jake";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(name) FROM persons WHERE name = "Jake";
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? Depending on the table, you can do something like:

`SELECT * FROM persons WHERE first_name = 'Jake'`

Which will return the number of rows with the first name of "Jake"

Alternatively, if you only want one row with the total count of occurrences:

`SELECT COUNT(first_name) FROM persons WHERE first_name = 'Jake'`

Comment: That will return all of the rows, not the number of occurrences

Answer (score 0):

Use group by statement on the column,  on which you are looking for duplicates if the count comes more than 1, it means they are repeating.

```
Select count(id), name from table_name group by id HAVING count(id) > 1;
```

Only the duplicates records will come.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `GROUP BY`.

A table contains multiple columns. You have to decide first which column(s) of the data that you need are in common.

Suppose I have a table address(person_name, plot_no, pin);

If I try to select, for a particulate pin, how many people are living there:

```
SELECT pin, COUNT(*)
FROM address
GROUP BY pin;
```

If I try to select, for a particulate plot_no and pin, how many people are living there:

```
SELECT plot_no, pin, COUNT(*)
FROM address
GROUP BY plot_no, pin;
```